# Ionic Cordova InAppBrowser Android LoadingSpinner

Tags: angular, android-studio, cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I need the Loadingspinner, because the loadingtime between the Pages are very huge. I can easy chance the LoadingSpinner in IOS, because i can set a default Loadingspinner. I can chance some settings in the native Code (color, size, etc). I knew thats a very ugly solution.
But i don't have a default loadingSpinner in Android. How can i create a Loadingspinner in the InAppBrowser for Android?

Comment: const browser = this.iab.create('https://ionicframework.com/');

browser.executeScript(...).subscribe(event => {
   ShowLoader Here
});


browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(event => {
   hideLoader Here
});

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need to implement ion-loading.

[Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/loading)

Comment: I try this but i want the loading overlaps the InAppBrowser. If i use the ion-loading, the loader is under the inAppBrowser. Everytime you chance the page, the loadingspinner is triggered.